# Modifying a string inside a function by passing by reference In C

Tags: c, malloc, pass-by-reference

So, I'm facing an issue that I don't really understand. Please be kind I'm trying to learn C by myself !

I have a function that is called ***secureInput()*** that takes a pointer to a string and a **size** so that, when the user has to type some input I can be sure that there is no buffer overflow. Now, the thing is that I want to modify the string without copying it so instead modifying it directly by it's memory address but it just crashes when the second character in user input is assigned. See comments to see where it crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int secureInput(char **str, int size);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *mystring = NULL; // Declaring it a null so that I use malloc later
    secureInput(&mystring, 10);
    printf("%s\n", mystring);

}


int secureInput(char **str, int size)
{
    *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) *size);  // Because **str is a null pointer, I use malloc to allocate memory.
    if (*str == NULL)
        return -1;

    int c = 0;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && count < size)
        /* Here is where it crashes.
         * But changing the bellow line as : *str[0][count++] = c;
         * works as expected. Also, using a temporary pointer
         * and later using it to replace *str, is also working
         */
    
        *str[count++] = c;
    *str[count] = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `*str[count++]` to `(*str)[count++]` and the other one.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you, it worked ! But now I don't understand what the issue was really.. Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: Your `str[count]` obtains an offset from the pointer passed to the function, not from the pointer allocated. Then `*` dereferences an illegal pointer. The function would be easier to write by returning the pointer (or `NULL`) instead of through an argument.

Comment: @Liwinux it's all about the rules of precedence! You can compare it to mathematical precedence. In C, array subscripting takes precedence of dereferencing of a pointer (see list here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: This can be simplified a little by using a local variable (`char *s = malloc(); *str = s;`) then using `s` for the rest of the function. This would also make error handing a bit easier (by not assigning to `*str` until the end), as you don't make any changers to the caller's data until you know you're done.

Comment: Also note that `(*str)[count]` potentially accesses past the end of the allocated space. You should either allocate one additional byte or read one less character.

Comment: Thank you all of those informations, I think I have a better understanding of what's going on with code and why I'm getting a SegFault ! I appreciate that !

Comment: I also added some explanation about pointer arithmetic, hope it helps to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

So first off, you can pass a string as a `char*`, no need for `char**`. That is usually used for an array of strings when passed as argument. Then, if you want to use a fixed size array, a buffer, that has a constant, pre-defined size, don't use malloc. Dynamic memory allocation is always inefficient and risky, so only use it if absolutely necessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

int secureInput(char *str, int size);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char mystring[BUFFER_SIZE]; // Declaring it a null so that I use malloc later
    memset(mystring, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    secureInput(mystring, BUFFER_SIZE);
    printf("%s\n", mystring);
}

int secureInput(char *str, int size) {

    char c = 0;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    
    c = getchar();
    while(c != '\n' && count < size - 1) {
        str[count++] = c;
        c = getchar();
    }
    str[count] = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I can see that there is still some confusion regarding the pointer arithmetic. Here is some address printing and a small figure, I hope it helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int secureInput(char **str, int size);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *mystring = NULL; // Declaring it a null so that I use malloc later
    secureInput(&mystring, 10);
}


int secureInput(char **str, int size) {
    *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) *size);  // Because **str is a null pointer, I use malloc to allocate memory.
    (*str)[0] = 'a';
    (*str)[1] = 'b';
    (*str)[2] = 'c';
    (*str)[3] = 0;
    printf("address of the pointer that points to a pointer that points the first char of the array : %p\n", &str);
    printf("value of the pointer that points to a pointer that points to the first char of the array : %p\n", str);
    printf("address of the pointer that points to the first char of the array : %p\n", &(*str));
    printf("value of the pointer that points to the first char of the array : %p\n", *str);
    printf("address of the first char of the array: %p\n", &(**str));
    printf("address of the seconds char of the array: %p\n", &((*str)[1]));
    printf("value of the first char of the array : %c\n", **str);
    printf("value of the second char of the array : %c\n", *(*str + 1));
    printf("value of the second char of the array : %c\n", (*str)[1]);
    printf("*str[1] is the same as *(str[1]), which runs to a segmentation fault\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
address of the pointer that points to a pointer that points the first char of the array : 0x7ffce24333f8
value of the pointer that points to a pointer that points to the first char of the array : 0x7ffce2433430
address of the pointer that points to the first char of the array : 0x7ffce2433430
value of the pointer that points to the first char of the array : 0x55a91985a2a0
address of the first char of the array: 0x55a91985a2a0
address of the seconds char of the array: 0x55a91985a2a1
value of the first char of the array : a
value of the second char of the array : b
value of the second char of the array : b
*str[1] is the same as *(str[1]), which runs to a segmentation fault
```

```
     0x7ffce24333f8              0x7ffce2433430              
   +----------------+          +----------------+          +----------------+
   | 0x7ffce2433430 | -------> | 0x55a91985a2a0 | -------> |       a        | 0x55a91985a2a0
   +----------------+          +----------------+          +----------------+
   
                                                           +----------------+
                                                           |       b        | 0x55a91985a2a1
                                                           +----------------+
   
                                                           +----------------+
                                                           |       c        | 0x55a91985a2a2
                                                           +----------------+
```

The point is that it matters which pointer you dereference.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I sould have said that my goal was to initialize my string inside a function hense the malloc function inside **SecureInput()**. So if you keep this in mind, the first argument of this function should be a double pointer as, a string is a pointer to the first character and so if I want to have a pointer to this we have to use a double pointer right ?

Comment: I just saw, your edited answer and THIS is really helpful, thank you for this man !

Comment: You are welcome. You are right, if you want to modify a value that is outside the function, you pass a pointer to it. If you want to modify a pointer that is used outside the function, you pass a pointer to it, hence a double pointer.

Comment: You are right, I did not notice the count vs size problem. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

At least this problem:

**Off by one**

`str[count] = '\0';` can write outside array bounds leading to OP''s trouble. Suggest `count < size` --> `count + 1 < size`.

**Entire line not always read**

Reading a partial line leads to trouble.

How about reading the entire line and report results?  Let calling code provide the buffer as it is of fixed size.

Distinguish between reading an empty line and end-of-file.

Handle `size == 0` gracefully.

```
// EOF: end-of-file with no input
// EOF: input error
// 0: input, but too much
// 1: Success
int secureInput(char *str, size_t size) {
  if (str == NULL) {
    size = 0;
  }

  bool too_many = false;
  size_t count = 0;
  int c;
  while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    if (c == EOF) {
      if (feof(stdin) && count > 0) {
        break;
      }
      if (size > 0) {
        str[0] = '\0';
      }
      return EOF;
    }

    if (count + 1 < size) {
      str[count++] = c;
    } else {
      too_many = true;
    }
  }

  if (count < size) {
    str[count] = '\0';
  } 
  return count < size && !too_many;
}
```